# Delete line that matches pattern and all subsequent lines until second pattern

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to use sed to delete line that matches specific pattern and all the subsequent lines until another pattern is found.

For example:

```
This is a line I want to delete,
this is second line that should be deleted.
And this is stop-pattern which should terminate deletion.
```

I want to delete the whole above paragraph giving sed two patterns **/delete,/** (which is the starting pattern and whole line containing that pattern should be deleted) and **/deletion./** (which is the pattern which determines the point where to stop deleting).

How do I write sed command which can accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
sed '/delete,/,/deletion\./d' file > outfile
```

Here,

- `/delete,/,/deletion\./` tells `sed` to match a portion of text between (and including) the lines, starting with one contraining `delete,` and ending with the line having `deletion.` (note `.` must be escaped to match a literal dot)
- `d` tells `sed` to remove that block of lines.

See an [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/1NJRoj).