# delete from a text file if matched the specific string

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm wirting the simple script for cleanup some unused strings.

and i used `awk '/^EEEEEEEEE$/,/^$/' file` to grep the scope which is need to delete.

As i know i can use `sed -i '/<parrten>/d'` file to delete a line from the file.

The intrest thing is when i combined them in the for loop then the sed command cannot delete lines, and i also checked the varibales in the for loop block the string is correct.

For Loop

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(awk '/^EEEEEEEEE$/,/^$/' file); do
  echo $i
  sed -i '/$i/d' file
done
```

File content:

```
AAAAAAA
BBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCC
DDDDDDD

EEEEEEEEE
FFFFFFFFF
GGGGGG

HHHHHHH
LLLLLLLLL
PPPPPPPP
```

I'm not sure there is any missing or incorrect. I just want to make sure can delet them

Comment: The single quotes prevent substitution. Try `echo '$PATH'` and compare that to `echo "$PATH"`.

Comment: Note that `awk '/^EEEEEEEEE$/,/^$/ {next} 1' file` would do the same as your complete script, without `sed`, and would also be much safer: no risk to delete partly matching lines, no need to consider lines with regex operators in them... If one of the lines to delete is `.*`, your script will delete all lines. If you have GNU `awk` use `awk -i inplace '/^EEEEEEEEE$/,/^$/ {next} 1' file` for in-place modification.

Comment: You might find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52621444/delete-line-that-matches-pattern-and-all-subsequent-lines-until-second-pattern) useful.

Comment: Usually when you use both `awk` and `sed` there is a way to simplify and use only one. Example with just `sed`: `sed -i '/^EEEEEEEEE$/,/^$/d' file`.

Comment: What is desired output for shown input?

Comment: You never need sed when you're using awk, you shouldn't use a shell loop for this (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219), if you did use a shell loop that's not how you'd write it (https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), and do as the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs and "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.".